# Goland can't get the correct current path when run and debug?

Tags: go, goland

When I invoke the following code,

```
 func GetCurrentDirectory() string {
    dir, err := filepath.Abs(filepath.Dir(os.Args[0]))
```

it returns:

> /private/var/folders/cg/mwzlhrjs5y55ny553g6xz9tr0000gn/T

Absolutely, it is a temp path, I excepted the path is my current directory, not temporary directory.

```
dir, err := filepath.Abs("")
```

could help me,but I must judge whether in run、debug mode in goland or not

Comment: "I excepted the path is my current directory". Why do you expect this? You use the  path of the executable and this is a temporary build. What is wrong with os.Getwd?

Comment: Because sometimes I will rely on the current shell script .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fix this, go to `Run | Edit Configuration... | <name of your configuration>`  and change the `Working Directory` property in order to change the working directory of the application or configure the `Output directory` in order to configure where the binary is created and run from (by default it's in the temporary directory of your OS).

Comment: Thank you, It works when I set the output directory.

Comment: That makes sense as you read the location of the binary itself instead of the working directory.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend adding a debug parameter.

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var debug bool
    flag.BoolVar(&debug, "d", false, "debug")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(debug)
}
```

Then pass `-d` it when you run the program from your IDE.

Comment: Does the go library have the variant to control whether in the IDE mode(run or debug) or in executable mode ?